# Creating a struct and printing out the contents

Tags: c

I am trying to create a struct using dynamic memory allocation,get input at run time and finally trying to print out the contents.

This is the code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>

  typedef struct island{//struct template
  char* name;
  char* opens;
  char* closes; 
  struct island *next;  
  }island;

void display(island *start)//start display
{
island *i;
i=start;
while(i!=NULL)
{
    printf("Name:%sOpen:%s-%s\n",i->name,i->opens,i->closes);
    i=i->next;
}   
}//end display

island *create(char *name)//start create
{
    island *i=malloc(sizeof(island));
    i->name=strdup(name);
    i->name=name;
    i->opens="9:00AM";
    i->closes="5:00PM";
    i->next=NULL;
    return i;
}//end create

int main()//start main
{
char name[80];
fgets(name,80,stdin);
island *i=create(name);
display(i);
return 0;
}//end-main
```

What we have here is an island struct,a display method to display the struct contents and then a create function which creates the space for the struct using dynamic memory allocation.I pass the name for the island at runtime and create the struct.

This is the output which I get and it works when I run the program:

```
 C:\Users\Gova\Desktop\ctest>testing
 Ami
 Name:Ami
 Open:9:00AM-5:00PM
```

Note:testing is the name of the program.

The problem is I am trying to print the output in this manner,and its not getting printed,why is that?

```
 C:\Users\Gova\Desktop\ctest>testing
 Ami
 Name:Ami Open:9:00AM-5:00PM
```

printf() statement used is:

```
 printf("Name:%sOpen:%s-%s\n",i->name,i->opens,i->closes);
```

Why does the program add a line break when I have not specified anything in the printf() statement?

Comment: `fgets` reads and stores a trailing `\n` character.

Comment: You also have another problem, since you seem to be learning dynamic memory allocation: you are not releasing the allocated memory. This is not a big issue in this program because once it terminates, memory is released. In a bigger and more long-living program, that behavior would generate a memory leak.

Comment: @kaylum,  Ok,got it,how can i avoid it?

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r ; Yeah,I forgot to use free(),thanks for the heads up